# Does anyone know how to resolve the error?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-bicep

Deploying using Azure bicep. I have a VM extension AADSSHLoginForLinux which is a Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory

[image]

I have followed guidelines in using az to add the Microsoft.Compute provider but still no change and its preventing me from provisioning a linux VM

Comment: can you check your az cli version? looks like you need to update az cli to latest version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/727655/vmcustomization-is-not-enabled-for-the-subscriptio

Comment: I am already on the latest version oa azcli

Comment: Could you please share your Azure CLI version? Also, verify that the  **Microsoft.Compute**  provider is registered in your subscription by using **az provider show --namespace Microsoft.Compute**, if not registered enable **az provider register --namespace Microsoft.Compute**

Comment: @venkat, The state is showing as registered and the azCli version is 2.56.0

Comment: Can you provide the **Bicep** code by editing the question? Also, try creating a VM using the CLI and check the result. az vm create \  
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \  
    --name myVM \  
    --image Win2019Datacenter \  
    --public-ip-sku Standard \  
    --admin-username azureuser

Comment: @VenkatV, please view bicep code https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Princetimber/Bicep-2/main/compute/linux/main.bicep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to resolve the error?

There is an issue in the `Bicep` code that caused the problem. The **vmSizeProperties** hash was incorrect

**Response:**

[image]

You can check the **features** enabled in your subscription by using the command below.

```
az feature show --namespace Microsoft.Compute --name VMCustomizationPreview
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can create an `Ubuntu Linux` virtual machine using a [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-bicep?tabs=CLI#review-the-bicep-file) file.

**Output:**

[image]

Refer the [VM deployment: Please register the Subscription for 'Microsoft.Compute/VMCustomizationPreview' to use the feature. - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1344921/vm-deployment-please-register-the-subscription-for) by `Ronny Forberger`

[Nested Virtualization in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/)

Comment: I removed the offending code which was a property of the VMSize. This is a preview feature which requires going back to MSFT to register for this feature. Thanks @venkatV for your assistance in resolving this topic.